# How to give boolean value to html in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, boolean

How do i give the `showProduct:boolean = false;` value to the `app-product` html selector so it will be false at start?

```js
showProduct:boolean = false;
```

```html
<button (click)="showProduct=!showProduct">Show Product</button>
<div *ngIf="!showProduct">
    <app-product></app-product>    
</div>
```

Comment: Your code seems correct, try to check that the HTML of the app-product component is not empty

Comment: If you are trying to pass an agument to the child component you need to use binding input property https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#binding-to-an-input-property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need **`<div *ngIf="showProduct">`**,

```
<button (click)="showProduct=!showProduct">Show Product</button>
<div *ngIf="showProduct">
    <app-product></app-product>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :D